# How can I create a web::uri from a string to put into client.connect()?

Tags: c++, websocket, cpprest-sdk

A `client.connect(web::uri)` is required, but after looking into `web::uri` it won't accept a string. The api seems to say it can accept a string, but it won't and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cpprest/ws_client.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::websockets::client;

int main(int argc, char **args) {

    uri link = uri("ws://echo.websocket.org"); //PROBLEM LINE
    websocket_client client;    
    client.connect(link).wait(); 

    websocket_outgoing_message out_msg;
    out_msg.set_utf8_message("test");
    client.send(out_msg).wait();

    client.receive().then([](websocket_incoming_message in_msg) {
        return in_msg.extract_string();
    }).then([](string body) {
        cout << body << endl;
    }).wait();

    client.close().wait();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: It takes a `utility::char_t *` not a c-string.

Comment: If your question has been answered satisfactorily, it would be nice for you to mark the answer as "accepted", and upvote if you found it particularly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A quick peek at the [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/include/cpprest/base_uri.h) of `uri` shows there's a constructor that takes a string argument, but it isn't a plain and simple C-type string:

```
_ASYNCRTIMP uri(const utility::char_t *uri_string);
```

If you're building this under windows, you may find that `utility::char_t` is in fact `wchar_t`, so you could prefix your URI string with an L to mark it as wide-character unicode, like this:

```
uri link = uri(L"ws://echo.websocket.org");
```

I believe there's a convenience cross-platform string macro provided by the library, `U()`. Have a look at the [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/FAQ). I assume it works a bit like this:

```
uri link = uri(U("ws://echo.websocket.org"));
```